# Jekyll css images not loading

Tags: jekyll

I'm starting to write a blog and I want to host it on Github, so I'm going to use Jekyll.

Everything is going fine, but I want to be able to use: http://zurb.com/playground/social-webicons

Those are just social icons that you can add with a simple line like:

```
<a href="#" class="fc-webicon facebook small">Like us on Facebook</a>
<a href="#" class="fc-webicon facebook">Like us on Facebook</a>
<a href="#" class="fc-webicon facebook large">Like us on Facebook</a>
```

I have followed the instructions but I can't make them work. Nothing shows up in my blog! So I'm sure there is a Jekyll related thing but after googling for a while I can't make them work.

I have copied the `webicons` folder and the `webicons.css` to the `css` folder, but it's not working (with not working I mean, it's not showing up the icon in the webpage)

This is how the `webicons.css` looks like:

```
.no-svg .webicon.foursquare.large {
  background: url("webicons/webicon-foursquare.png");
}
```

And of course, if I go to: `http://0.0.0.0:4000/css/webicons/webicon-git-m.png` I can see the image.

But If I add:

```
   <a href="#" class="fc-webicon facebook small">Like us on Facebook</a>
```

Nothing shows up in my page. It's driving me crazy!! what's happening!?!?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is a Jekyll thing, I suspect that either the file paths are wrong or that you are not loading the webicons.css. Did you add a link to webicons.css in your page ?

If you share a link to your site people could tell you exactly what the issue is…

Answer (score 1):

Juan , recently I faced same kind of issue , you see I was using font-awesome version 4.2 , and I couldn't get the promised view , after that I tried the typical **Liquid** type of template language ,

like ,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "./css/fontawesome.css" | prepend : site.baseurl }}"/>
```

But still its no result for me,

after that I used fontawesome **CDN** and yes I solved the problem .

You can try any other icon pack or if you can a hosted url of that icon pack , for more help please check ,

[http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/]

I hope this will help ..